# How to set a image/icon width that was specified through css content property?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<h2>Some title</h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2::after{
   content: url(ok.png);
}
```

It is possible to set a width to "ok.png" image, using the above rule (with content)?

http://jsfiddle.net/zumv5z6e

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve from your code above? You can try add "position:absolute, width: Npx" to your after rule.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zumv5z6e/ - I want to set the size of the image width to 24px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything you want in the CSS block for ::after.  See here for more info on pseudo elements: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

```
h2::after {
    background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/tick_ok_sign_4190.jpg);
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: 20px;
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/syf80qta/

Comment: I need the image positioned at right side of <h2> and not below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use width and height function

```
h2::after{ content: url(ok.png); width: 20px; height:20px; }
```